# move_uploaded_file is not moving images from temp folder to upload folder in php

Tags: php, file-upload

While uploading images it is not seen in "upload" folder and showing error but not specifying what is the error. but when I work with this code it was working perfectly earlier. Don't know what happened now. I can't find anything wrong with my code.Please review my code and help me to find the error

```
<?php
   include('database.php');
   if(isset($_POST['addproduct']))
   {
    $prod_name=$_POST['prod_name'];
    $prod_family=$_POST['prod_family'];
    $sur_finish=$_POST['sur_finish'];
    $type=$_POST['type'];
    $size=$_POST['size'];
    $application = implode(" & ",$_POST['application']);

    $image=$_FILES['prod_image']['name'];
    $imgtmp=$_FILES['prod_image']['tmp_name'];
    $location="upload";

    $uploading=move_uploaded_file($imgtmp,"upload/".$image);

    if($uploading)      
    {
    echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "error".mysqli_error($con);
    }
    $upfile="upload/".$image;       
    $qry = "insert into products values('','$prod_name','$prod_family','$sur_finish','$type','$size','$application','$upfile')";
    $ex=mysqli_query($con,$qry);

    }
 ?>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: it is not showing any error

Comment: put `if(move_uploaded_file($imgtmp,"upload/".$image))`

Comment: I already checked if($uploading)      
    {
    echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "error".mysqli_error($con);
    }

Comment: but its not showing error it only echo "error"

Comment: why should mysql be able to tell you what went wrong with the upload? It has nothing to do with it...

Comment: Yeah...so that I can't find what is the error. Can anyone see the error in the code

Comment: Hi all,
I found it.The code has no error and I think the problem is on file size because some images are uploading. But problem is  its echoing "error", don't know why it is